# Startup Applications aside from startup folder and msconfig

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, msconfig

Is there any place (such as the registry) where startup items could be stored? As far as I can tell Fraps "start on windows" does not appear in msconfig or the startup folder. I am running windows 7

Comment: FWIW, I dont think this is a duplicate of "What is the best software for managing startup applications?"  One question is asking where, the other is asking about software.

Comment: Sufficient funds for autoruns use known keys. By the way I wonder what you will say when you see the new Trojans in unusual places. If we are talking about protection, it is best way to take an interest in the curvature of the system.

Comment: @Karan, Ok. This is a dangerous question about dangerous knowledge. Willful disregard for the safety of other criminal. Thanks for the advice, but I have decided where your opinion. I do not know English, barbarian forgivable). As for the "curvature of the system" - it is a form of protection when the systemic mechanisms violated. For example, changing the response TTL. Lock on uprovne system run executable files. I think nobly not to endanger other people without posting dangerous knowledge. No harm. It is important to see how the instrument behaves in the wrong hands.

Comment: Incidentally, the hacking is not bad, as long as it does not harm others.

Comment: @Keltari: IMO it *is* a dupe because of the X-Y problem. The first sentence may make it seem as if the OP wants a list of all possible locations, but it's clear what he *actually* wants to do is figure out how Fraps is auto-starting. The answers here will help him, and he'll find the same information on that other question's page as well.

Comment: @Karan. Skip if I mind? Excellent. Outside, someone hit and pass? Do not really understand. Said it was important. 1. These keys and places to eat. 2. Their knowledge is harmful to the absolute majority. Well, this is something like the creation of explosives from household funds. This is also useful?

Comment: @Karan. Code and images much easier. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I use sysinternals [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx), this shows you pretty much *everything* that automatically starts up on your machine.

Comment: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Notify` subkey - not view, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` GinaDLL and more registry and command files)) ... it is often known keys isspolzuemye vendors of large companies for their protection and virus writers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are usually stored in the registry. There are several programs like [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) that you can use to manage these processes.

[image: Startup tab in CCleaner]

You can also see them in the registry as you can see from the pic above they are in the Run section in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` aka `HKCU` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` aka `HKLM`.
If you want to find them just type `regedit.exe` into the Run dialog in Start menu. Then click to `HKCU` or `HKLM` and after it to the followings:
`Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Run`

[image: Startup programs in regedit.exe]

Here you can see my `HKLM` (top) and `HKCU` (bottom) processes in the Run section.

Comment: i searched the registry for fraps, and it returned no results that would seem to be autostart. Also Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Run contained no entries